# an "Invalid Class String" error when saving SSIS

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I have installed VS SSDT 2017, and SQL SERVER 2016 in my server.
Created a new SSIS project and I try to save the package.
On the dialog box, I use windows authentication
Then I click the "..." button on the package path to browse for it, and I get the following error:

“ Invalid class string “

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can repair or re/install a new SSMS that might help.